# Simple Lie algebra representations and tensor powers of fundamental representations

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $\frak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. We will call a representation of $\frak{g}$ **tautological** if it is a fundamental representation of smallest dimension.

For $V$ a tautological representation, can all representations of $\frak{g}$ be realised as a sub-representation of some tensor power of $V$?

My intuiton here comes from the A-series . . .

Comment: So it seems this question has already been asked and answered

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310296/when-can-you-build-up-all-representations-from-the-fundamental-and-antifundament?rq=1

Comment: I propose somebody with the power close this question

Comment: as a duplicate.